Halide app using CUDA gives bad allocation compile error
I have a little familiarity with Halide and am trying to get started with using CUDA from Halide. I have a laptop with an NVidia RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU. I installed CUDA 12.5. I tried building one of the apps that comes with the Halide 17.0.1 Source code: cuda_mat_mul. You can see the code at https://github.com/halide/Halide/tree/main/apps/cuda_mat_mul
I use Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11.
I get the following Build error:
>------ Rebuild All started: Project: cuda_mat_mul, Configuration: x64-Debug ------
  [1/1] Cleaning all built files...
  Cleaning... 0 files.
  [1/9] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\mat_mul.generator.dir\C_\etc\Personal\Imaging\Halide-17.0.1-x86-64-windows\share\Halide\tools\GenGen.cpp.obj
  [2/9] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\mat_mul.generator.dir\mat_mul_generator.cpp.obj
  [3/9] Linking CXX executable mat_mul.generator.exe
  [4/9] Generating mat_mul.h, mat_mul.obj
  FAILED: mat_mul.h mat_mul.obj C:/Users/cordo/source/repos/cuda_mat_mul/out/build/x64-Debug/mat_mul.h C:/Users/cordo/source/repos/cuda_mat_mul/out/build/x64-Debug/mat_mul.obj 
  cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\cordo\source\repos\cuda_mat_mul\out\build\x64-Debug && C:\Users\cordo\source\repos\cuda_mat_mul\out\build\x64-Debug\mat_mul.generator.exe -n mat_mul -d 0 -g mat_mul -f mat_mul -e c_header,object -o . target=host-cuda-cuda_capability_86-no_runtime size=1024"
  Unhandled exception: bad allocation
  [5/9] Generating mat_mul.runtime.obj
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Rebuild All failed.

Prior to the build, CMake gave the following output:
1> CMake generation started for configuration: 'x64-Debug'.
1> Found and using vcpkg toolchain file (C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake).
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\cordo\source\repos\cuda_mat_mul\out\install\x64-Debug" -DHalideHelpers_DIR:PATH="C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/Halide-17.0.1-x86-64-windows/lib/cmake/HalideHelpers" -DHalide_DIR:PATH="C:\etc\Personal\Imaging\Halide-17.0.1-x86-64-windows\lib\cmake\Halide" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\Ninja\ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "C:\Users\cordo\source\repos\cuda_mat_mul" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:\Users\cordo\source\repos\cuda_mat_mul\out\build\x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31629.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31629.0
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.5 (found version "12.5") 
1> [CMake] -- Halide 'host' platform triple:   x86-64-windows
1> [CMake] -- Halide 'cmake' platform triple:  x86-64-windows
1> [CMake] -- Halide default AOT target:       host
1> [CMake] -- Found ZLIB: optimized;C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found version "1.2.13") 
1> [CMake] -- Found PNG: optimized;C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/libpng16.lib;debug;C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libpng16d.lib (found version "1.6.37") 
1> [CMake] -- Found JPEG: optimized;C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/jpeg.lib;debug;C:/etc/Personal/Imaging/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/jpeg.lib (found version "62") 
1> [CMake] -- Looking for pthread.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Found Threads: TRUE  
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] -- Generating done
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/cordo/source/repos/cuda_mat_mul/out/build/x64-Debug
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted toolchain configurations.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> CMake generation finished.


Any suggestions on how I would go about finding the issue?

That's not a compile error, it's a C++ runtime error within the host halide code. Something in that example is broken or you ran out of CPU memory,  which I doubt

It turned out to be caused by the build type being set to "Debug". Setting it to "Release" fixed it.
